# Flipping coins in 2 moves

Tags: combinatorics

If we have $5$ coins, each of them tails up, and flip $3$ coins at time (any $3$ coins), then is it possible to get all coins heads up in $2$ moves?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Each flip changes the parity of the number of tails up.  After two flips you will have an odd number of tails up, so will not have zero.